# Code worked initially but no longer works, uses "split" command, and basic string handling

Tags: string, split

I have a piece of code that is supposed to give a preset response when the user says "screen", I got this code to work but when I came back to it later without making any changes it stopped working. Here is the code:

```
file = open('phone_help_answers.txt',"r")
lines = file.readlines()

key_words_screen_1 = "screen"

user_input=input("What is your issue?")
string=user_input

for i in string.split(' '):
    if i == key_words_screen_1:
        def read():
            with open('phone_help_answers.txt', 'r') as file:
                print (lines[3])
```

Additionally certain letters will give my other preset responses.

Comment: UPDATE: I have narrowed the problem down to me being unable to open and display the text file correctly

Comment: You might want to tag the question with the programming language

Comment: Apologies, I am new here. I did add tags of things like "string" but some seem to have deleted themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, I just remove the "def read()" and leave only the "pinrt (lines[3])